# How to tell when somebody is reading an item from a CollectionBase

Tags: c#, ilist, virtualmode, collectionbase

I'm not sure if this is possible using a CollectionBase class.  I'd like to know when somebody is accessing an item in a CollectionBase class.

The final goal is to create a "VirtualMode" (similar to the DataGridView control) that allows me to check and validate the data going out prior to the user getting it.

So what would happen is they could create a collection of say, 20 objects, internally we modify the IList to contain 20 null objects, then when they attempt to read an item, if it is null, we go to the external data source and read it in at that time.  Then we replace the existing null object with the read class and next time they try to access it, they get the cached version.

After typing that out.  I wonder if the OnValidate might be the right spot to do that.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Trevor Watson

Comment: what version of c# are you using?

Comment: how do they attempt to read the item? by index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with a `CollectionBase`. `OnValidate()` is only called prior to `OnInsert()`,`OnRemove()`, and `OnSet()`.

You can inherit from `ArrayList` and override the indexer property ([`ArrayList.Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.item.aspx)).

Comment: ArrayList is the one I want.  Thanks.  I was using CollectionBase from habit, but ArrayList has 

`public override object this[int index]`

which is exactly what I need to do

Another thing I just noticed about ArrayList is that it can't be strongly typed.  But that's fine for me really.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking for a virtualizing collection. [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfDataVirtualization.aspx) on CodeProject has a nice implementation (it's intended for data binding in WPF, but it can probably be used in another context)